# Integrating stripe with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, payment-processing, stripe-payments

I am following along with railscast #288 on stripe but I am having some difficulty with setting the stripe hidden token. I am using the most recent version of devise with simple form integration.

Here is my Registrations Controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    build_resource 
    if resource.save_with_payment
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

My form for registering a new user:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'well'} ) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <h3 class="center">Create your credentials for logging in:</h3><hr>
  <div class="inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, :required => true  %>
    <%= f.input :password, :required => true %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>
  <h3 class="center">Are you a Shipper or a Carrier?</h3><hr>
    <%= f.input :role, :collection => User::ROLES, :as => :radio_buttons %>
    <%= f.input :stripe_card_token, :as => :hidden %>
  </div>
  <h3 class="center">Your Credit Card Information:</h3><hr>
  <fieldset>
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
      <div class="input-prepend inline-block">
      <span class="add-on"><strong>#</strong></span>
      <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Back of Card (CVV)" %>
      <div class="input-prepend inline-block">
      <span class="add-on icon-credit-card"></span>
      <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil, :size => 4  %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
      <%= select_month nil, { add_month_numbers: true }, { name: nil, id: "card_month" } %>
      <%= select_year nil, { start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15 },
  { name: nil, id: "card_year" } %>
    </div>
    <div id="stripe_error">
      <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <hr>
  <%= f.input :terms, :as => :boolean, label: "* I have read and agreed to the terms of service" %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up", class: "btn-large icon-thumbs-up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have a user model with the following attributes:

```
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :role, :terms, :stripe_token, :stripe_card_token
```

And Finally the coffeescript to get this all to work correctly:

```
jQuery ->
Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
subscription.setupForm()

subscription = 
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_user').submit ->
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
        if $('#card_number').length
            subsciption.processCard()
            false
        else
            true

processCard: ->
    card =
        number: $('#card_number').val()
        cvc: $('#card_code').val()
        expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
        expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, subscription.handleStripeResponse)

handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
        $('#user_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
        $('#new_user')[0].submit()
    else 
        $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

When I go to create a new user my action controller is giving me the following error message:

```
undefined method `stripe_card_token' for #<User:0x00000103fe7b90>
```

However I don't think this should be possible since I have defined this method in my attr_accessible call in my user.rb model. Any explanation would be really helpful, as I think i am 90% of the way to being done with setting this up.

Answer (score 5):

Unless `stripe_card_token` is a field in your Users table, you'll want to make it an `attr_accessor` (as well as `attr_accessible`).

Comment: That's interesting, I thought that `attr_accessible` would be also doing `attr_accessor`. Would you know why it's not? thanks